# Is it impossible to find the exact analytic form of the molar volume of liquid and gas in phase transition from the van der Waal equations?

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to find the molar volume $v_g$, $v_l$ of gas and liquid respectively in the coexistence curve of phase diagram with given temperature when ideal van der Waal gas
$$ P = \frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v^2}$$
is given as underlying fundamental equation.
I read the Lekner's parametric solution part of https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1205. Following that parametric solution, we can find $v_g, v_l$ if the molar entropy difference $\Delta s $ for that point of the coexistence curve is given.

But it seems that there is no analytic method to find $\Delta s $ value other than experimental measurement. Is it true? Is there any analytic method to find the analytic form of $v_g ,v_l$ exactly from the ideal van der Waals equation?